# Differential equation with terminal condition.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$ \frac{\partial B(t,T)}{\partial t} = kB(t,T)-1, \quad B(T,T) = 0.  $$

but I don't see where I should start. A hint would be appreciated and then I (hopefully) should be able to carry out the calculations myself.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the differential equation, ignore $T$.  It is just $\frac{dB}{dt}=kB-1$.  You will have a constant $C$ as part of your answer.
Now bring back $T$.  The constant $C$ is now $C(T)$.  Choose $C(T)$ so that, when you set $t=T$, B becomes zero.